Repository Temporarily Unavailable During Hackathon
I'm currently participating in a hackathon with my development team, and we're facing an issue that's impacting our progress. For the past 2 hours, we've been seeing this message when trying to access our repository:
 


This repository is temporarily unavailable.
The backend storage is temporarily offline. Usually this means the storage server is undergoing maintenance. Please contact support if the problem persists.

Given that we're in the middle of a time-sensitive project, I'm concerned about the impact this downtime is having on our development.

Is this message typically indicative of scheduled maintenance, or could there be a more urgent issue with the server?

Are there any immediate steps we can take to continue working while the repository is down?

What are the best practices for dealing with such situations during critical development phases like hackathons?


